# Can the keyboard layout name on the panel be edited?

Tags: keyboard, language

Among others I often switch by short-key between two different layouts of the same language: English (US) and English (US, international with dead keys). But both are indicated in the panel with the same name: **us**.

In other systems I have seen these differentiated somehow: when a second layout of US English is added, it is displayed as 'us.', a third one as 'us..', etc, and in KDE the name displayed can be completely customized.

Is there some place where I can edit to differentiate those two layouts in the panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually using only the language code (and nothing of the variant) is hard-coded in the source of `wingpanel-indicator-keyboard`. So you can either edit the source code or open a feature request.

Comment: as a workaround, I use this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1079173/47206